# What does this regular expression means?

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression in the code `^(\s*\n)+`

Can any body please explain what is it looking for?

I am sorry for this silly question..i spent hours but could not get the answer

Comment: A string starting with 0 or more whitespace characters, at least one newline characters, optionally repeated (so more whitespace characters, yet another newline character, etc.).

Comment: There are a number of very handy regular expression explanation tools online, e.g. [this one](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=^%28\s*\n%29%2B) or [this one](http://regex101.com/r/eO4qY1) or many others.

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the links..I knew only gskinner regex

Comment: @DSM: And none of them can explain what the regex tries to do. The most is the syntax

Comment: `+` is useless in above regex

Comment: @DSM I must really thank you...because i tried this regex in the gskinner site and it was showing nothing..but when i tried in the regex101 shared by you..it is clearly showing this is matching for the first blank lines. Thanks once again

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is what we once called "too localized".  This sort of question should not be allowed because anyone could post a what does this regular expression mean question and this site would be flooded with them

Answer (score 6):

`^` matches the start of a string. `\s` matches whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.). `*` means "match none or more" of these. `\n` is a newline. The parentheses group these together in a capturing group. The `+` means "match one or more" of the preceding expression.

Together this matches all blank and blank-*looking* lines at the beginning of your string.

Comment: `\s` can also match new line character, and it is where it becomes interesting. Another thing is that depending on flag, there might be some change in the behavior of the regex...

Comment: Apparently there are some regex dialects in which `\s` only matches a space. If it also matches `\n`, as it usually does, the `+` is redundant. But yeah, this is definitely at least a multiline regex, which is not how regexes typically work by default.

Comment: `Apparently there are some regex dialects in which \s only matches a space.` Which one?

Comment: Beats me. Certainly none I've ever used.

Answer (score 1):

The regex will match at the beginning of a string (or a beginning of a line - depending on the flag) `^`, and match as many blank lines as possible `(\s*\n)+`. Blank lines are lines that consists of only whitespace characters as defined by `\s`. The `\n` at the end makes sure to limit the match to the end of a blank line and not to spill over to a sequence of whitespace characters at the beginning of a line which does not entirely consist of whitespace characters.

Ignoring the capturing group, the regex is equivalent to:

```
^\s*\n
```

The reason is that `\s` is a short-hand character class that matches any whitespace character, which can also match new line character.

If you want the capturing group:

```
^(\s*\n)
```

Note that the repetition in the original regex is redundant, since the greedy quantifier of `\s*` has already consumed the longest possible string, and there is no way for a second iteration of the repetition to occur.

Depending on the language, `\s` may match slightly **different** set of whitespace character. However, in most regex flavors, space (ASCII 32), horizontal tab `\t`, new line `\n` and carriage return `\r` are matched by `\s`. Beyond that, `\s` may match Unicode whitespace character (e.g. .NET), or not (Java). Refer to the specific documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It means, match any string starting with (`^`) zero or more spaces (`\s*`) followed by a new line character (`\n`) and followed by any number (`+` denoting one or more) of the combination (`\s*\n`).

The parentheses are simply for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Match from beginning of string(`^`) any one of `[ \t\r\n]` 0 or more times until the last `\n`.

So with this regex you are basically trying to match

**1 or more** empty lines(i.e containing only `[ \t\r\n]`) at the **beginning** of string

---

`+` in the above regex is **redundant** and so doesn't make any difference! `^(\s*\n)` is correct!

Comment: `[ \t\r\n]` is the common set, but not all. Depending on the language, there can be more characters matched by `\s`.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes indeed..you are right but blame it on op who has not specified any language..:P

Answer (score -2):

It gives you the first lines (which are empty or have only whitespace characters) of a string, each in a capture group

- `^` marks the beginning of a string
- `( .. )+` matches strings using the regex within the parenthesis multiple times (but at least once)
- `\s*` matches none, or any number of whitespace characters `[ \t\r\n]`, eventually more depending on your programming language
- `\n` matches a newline

Comment: Not really the first line. It can actually match multiple empty lines.

Comment: Edited my answer a second before your comment ;)

Comment: Do you mean the beginning of my answer? It says "It gives you the first line*s*"

Comment: Yes, I am referring to that. There can be several blank lines at the beginning of the string, and the regex will match all of them.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had that in mind - so my eyes tricked me. Thanks.

Comment: By the way `\n` is a whitespace character. So it was technically correct. ;)